# Gcloud, Cloud build: Update all cloud run services with new image at once

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a Cloud Build trigger that push an image to container registry when a new commit is pushed on master branch.

When this occurs, I would like to update all my cloud run jobs with newly created image.

```
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - beta
      - run
      - jobs
      - update
      - $_JOB_ID_1
      - '--platform=managed'
      - '--image=$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
```

The problem is that I have like N jobs ids (job-id1; job-id2 .... job-idN). Is there a way to iterate over an array I would give as substitution variable to update all jobs at once ?

Comment: Not out of the box, but Cloud Workflows could help you a lot on that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do it like this:

```
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    env:
      - HOST=$_GCR_HOSTNAME
      - PROJECT=$PROJECT_ID
      - REPO=$REPO_NAME
      - SERVICE=$_SERVICE_NAME
      - COMMIT=$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Deploy Jobs
    script: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      jobs=$(gcloud beta run jobs list --format="value(name)")
      for job in $jobs; do
        if [[ $job == *"prod"* ]]; then
          gcloud beta run jobs update $job --image=$HOST/$PROJECT/$REPO/$SERVICE:$COMMIT --region=europe-southwest1
        fi
      done
```

Comment: I'm not sure the env variables here are correct anymore. I n33ded to wrap them in single quotations.

Comment: Also, how do we make sure the build fails if one of the job updates fails?